# What is needed in addition to suffixed resource folders (values-es) to support multiple languages in an app (Android)?

Tags: android, textview, android-resources

It looks like the way to support another language is to include extra folders, like `values-es`. Great, but I don't understand how the app will know which resources to load. When a Spanish speaker downloads my app from Google Play, will it just *know* to load from `values-es` based on her phone settings? How can I test this behavior before publishing an apk with both English and Spanish?

Answer (score 2):

> When a Spanish speaker downloads my app from Google Play, will it just know to load from values-es based on her phone settings?

Yes.

> How can I test this behavior before publishing an apk with both English and Spanish?

Set your phone or emulator to Spanish. You can find that in the Settings app.